# Почему строка изменяется?

Tags: c++, c, строки, указатели, char

Хотел просто вставить символ в строку.

```
void insert( char* str, const char ch, unsigned int pos ){

     unsigned int sz = strlen( str ) + 1;      //беру длину +1 для 0
     char* buf = new char[ sz + 1 ];           //создаю новый буфер
     memcpy( buf, str, sz * sizeof( char ) );  //копирую содержимое в него
     delete []str;                             //удаляю старую строку
     str = buf;                                //даю адрес на новую строку (! мб из за этого ошибка?)
     for( unsigned int i = sz; i >= pos; --i ){//сдвиг символов
          str[i+1] = str[i];
          if( i==0 ) break;
     }
     str[ pos ] = ch;                          //вставка символов
     str[ sz ]=0;                              //0 в конец
     printf("str: [%s]\n", str);               //вывод как надо "abcdefg"
}

int main(){

    char* str = new char[7];
    memcpy( str, "abcefg", 7 * sizeof( char ));
    printf( "str: [%s]\n", str ); //вывод нормальный

    insert( str, 'd', 3 );
    printf( "str: [%s]\n", str ); //вывод ▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌, в дебагере str = "ЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭ" -35

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас какое-то смешение стилей программирования C и C++. Поэтому если бы не присутствие оператора `new`, то можно было бы сделать вывод, что программа написана на языке C.

Что касается функции. Параметры функции являются локальными переменными функции. Функция имеет дело с **копией значения** исходного аргумента `str`, объявленного в `main`. Поэтому данное предложение в функции

```
str = buf;
```

не изменяет значение исходного указателя, объявленного в `main`. Оно меняет значение одноименной локальной переменной функции `str`.

В то же время внутри функции происходит удаление памяти, на которую указывает исходный указатель. Поэтому после выхода из функции исходный указатель `str` будет содержать некорректное значение, и программа будет иметь неопределенное поведение, пытаясь обратиться к памяти, адресуемой этим указателем.

Необходимо передавать первый аргумент в функцию либо по ссылке, либо через указатель на аргумент.

Когда вы имеете дело со строками, то в общем случае нет необходимости использовать функцию `memcpy`. Эта функция предназначена для копирования "сырых" байтов. Вам же лучше использовать стандартную функцию `strcpy`.

Все стандартные функции, которые имеют дело со строками обычно возвращают указатель на результирующую строку. Поэтому и вам следует придерживаться этого правила.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, в которой показано, как функция может быть реализована, когда первый параметр объявлен как указатель на исходный аргумент. Альтернативой было бы объявить первый параметр как ссылку.

```
char * insert( char * &s, char c, size_t pos );
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

Имейте также в виду, что стандартная функция `strlen` имеет тип возвращаемого значения `size_t` точно также, как и оператор `sizeof`. Поэтоу вам следует объявлять переменные с этим типом, которые будут хранить соответствующие значения, возвращаемые этой функцией. Иначе для очень больших строк может также возникнуть проблема неопределенного поведения программы.

И кроме того, вам следует проверять в функции корректность задаваемой позиции для вставки нового элемента. Если позиция выходит за допустимый диапазон, то функция может просто вернуть исходную строку, не изменяя ее.

Вот сама демонстрационная программа

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

char * insert( char **s, char c, size_t pos )
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( *s );

    if ( !( n < pos ) )
    {
        n += 2;

        char *tmp = new char[ n ];

        size_t i = 0;
        for ( ; i < pos; i++ ) tmp[i] = s[0][i];

        tmp[i++] = c;

        for ( ; i < n; i++ ) tmp[i] = s[0][i-1];

        delete [] *s;

        *s = tmp;
    }

    return *s;
}

int main() 
{
    char* str = new char[7];

    std::strcpy( str, "abcefg" );

    std::printf( "str: [%s]\n", str );

    std::printf( "str: [%s]\n", insert( &str, 'd', 3 ) ); 

    delete [] str;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
str: [abcefg]
str: [abcdefg]
```

Желательно в конце программы освободить выделенную память.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы изменить указатель передавайте в функцию **указатель на указатель**. Иначе получается, что вы меняете локальную копию указателя, а память по старому адресу (но актуальному вне функции) освобождаете. Из-за этого получаете мусор, пытаясь вывести строку по **старому** (так и не измененному) указателю.

Comment: Только надо было дописать, что при работе надо этот указатель разыменовывать, т.е. писать `delete []*str; *str = buf;`. Между прочим, раз есть delete - значит, у автора С++, так что лучше передавать ссылку на указатель, а не указатель на указатель!

Comment: @Mikhailo То, что указатели нужно разыменовывать для доступа к значению мне кажется очевидным. В отличие от передачи по неконстантной ссылке, которую, кстати говоря, стоит избегать без особого на то повода.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete []str;
```

Вы удалили память, на которую указывала переменная `str`, и там теперь мусор.

```
str = buf;
```

А здесь вы записали новый адрес в переменную, которая является аргументом функции `insert()`, но на значении переменной `str` в вызывающем коде это никак не скажется.

Чтобы изменить указатель снаружи функции можно пойти двумя путями:

1. Передавать не указатель, а его адрес
2. Возвращать новое значение из функции

Answer (score 2):

Замените `insert` на такую:

```
void insert( char*& str, const char ch, unsigned int pos )
```

(Т.е. используйте передачу по ссылке.)

И еще - исправьте цикл `for`:

```
 for( unsigned int i = sz-1; i >= pos; --i ){//сдвиг символов
```

Если, как у вас, `unsigned int i = sz;` - **вы выходите за границу выделенной памяти**, что здоровья программе не прибавляет.